# Build a 3 column, 2 row flex grid layout with first item spanning both rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically I'm trying to code this:

[image: Grid Layout]

I'm pretty sure it can be built with Flex but I just can't seem to get it working (and be responsive).  Responsively it would be nice to move the 4 blocks on the right under the main large left block at smaller screen sizes.

I'm building this out in a WP loop, but pretty comfortable with that part of it, just can't get the actual HTML/CSS Structure to work.

Here's what I've tried so far (And failed!):

HTML/Loop

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<div class="featured-posts-query">';
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <div class="featured-posts">
                    <div class="featured-posts-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail("thumbnail");?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="posts-category">
                    <?php $postType = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
if ($postType) {
echo esc_html($postType->labels->singular_name);
} ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="featured-posts-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h3> 
                                <?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 40, '...'); ?>
                            </h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>


    <? endwhile; 
    echo '</div>';
    do_action( 'genesis_after_endwhile1' );
endif;
wp_reset_query();
}
```

CSS

```
.featured-posts-query {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 550px;
  width: 102%;
}

.featured-posts:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 53%;
}

.featured-posts:nth-child(n+2) {
  flex: 0 0 49%;
  width:20%;
}
```

Comment: Can you use grid?

Comment: I'm open to any options as long as it's relatively supported in modern browsers. :)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: It is. And if you have mobile fallbacks, you don't have to worry about Opera Mini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use grid, it get's pretty easy.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jonschmitz/full/LmaJmj

Comment: Thanks Jons - That kind of works, however the first 'column' is wider than the other 2 in my image, is there a way to make that first block wider?

Comment: Hey Jons, Just realised why this won't work with Grid. I need Flex because I need the structure to stay the same... so the left image height needs to resize to match the height of the right columns so they all line up...  Looks like Grid doesn't do that.  https://imgur.com/a/NfUrEAf  :(